# Windows 10 how to force domain users to logon with temporary profile

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, domain, windows-10

We have one special computer in our company and we need it to be always "fresh". When there was windows7 all users where logged there with temporary profile and everything was great. Unfortunately after upgrade to Windows 10 users are getting local profile (on normal domain computers they have roaming profiles with folder redirection) and after many hours of tries I can't force windows 10 to log them in with temporary profile.

Is there any way to force users to logon always with temporary profile? Our domain controller is Win2008R2.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the temp profile?  If you share your goal someone may have a better path than a temp profile.

Answer (score 3):

The local group **guest** is done for that. Any member of that group on the server/computer will got a temporary profile *even* if a local profile is already on the machine. Thus that setting ignore local profile and give everyone a new temporary profile

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Set roaming profile path for all users logging onto this computer` policy value in computer configuration on a GPO targeting only that one PC.

If you set the path to something invalid, any user will always be logged on with a temporary profile.

Comment: It's a little bit dirty solution, but quite easy to do, I'll try it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

**Adding a user to the guest group deletes their userprofile at logoff**. Which makes their userprofile temporary, but *does not create for them a temporary profile*. In your situation, this may be an ideal solution.

It will not work for me as I want to be able to restore the original user profile. Removing the user's rights to their own profile does log them into a new TEMP profile until their permissions are restored.